# database user "postgres" is not the install user

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm trying to upgrade postgres from 9.5 to 9.6. 
`brew upgrade postgresql` succeeds, but when running

```
pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/bin/ -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin/ -d /usr/local/var/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres9.6 -U postgres
```

I get an error

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is the install user
database user "postgres" is not the install user
Failure, exiting
```

when trying without `-U postgres` at the end it gets even weirder

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is the install user                  ok
Checking database connection settings                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for reg* system OID user data types                ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Checking for roles starting with 'pg_'                      ok
Creating dump of global objects                             ok
Creating dump of database schemas
                                                            ok
Checking for presence of required libraries                 ok
Checking database user is the install user
database user "dimid" is not the install user
```

So how come

```
Checking database user is the install user                  ok
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The old PostgreSQL cluster was obviously created with

```
initdb -U dimid
```

but the new cluster was istalled with a different superuser.

You have to create the new cluster with the same superuser name as the old one.

Comment: Thanks, how can I find out which user created a cluster?

Comment: You would do that with `SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE oid = 10`, but it is not necessary. Just drop the new cluster and recreate it with `-U dimid`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Out of curiosity, what does `10` refer to?

Comment: That's the hard-coded `Oid` for the bootstrap superuser. Search the source for `BOOTSTRAP_SUPERUSERID`.

Comment: Note: if you're using postgres.app, it seems two roles are installed: $USER and 'postgres'.  This will also choke pg_upgrade (which expects a single non-system role), so you should run: `DROP DATABASE $USER; DROP ROLE $USER`

Answer (score 5):

Specifically for homebrew postgresql installations, the default user for initdb is $USER -- so if you just followed the instructions initially and did something like

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

the install user is your Unix username.  In my case it is 'rob', so just adding '-U rob' to the pg_upgrade works as well:

```
pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.4_1/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres95 -D /usr/local/var/postgres -U rob
```

Comment: for a lot of others the user may be postgres so just use that instead if this error message comes up with your name as not the install user

Comment: Yes, 'postgres' is the preferred install user as that is the default, and thus what users (like me) will try first.  Using $USER for the initial initdb as described in this answer is specific to homebrew installations of PostgreSQL on OSX / MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

For users of macOS Postgres App:

The upgrade script checks if $USER has the oid `10` in the old database, if this user does not exist – it responds with a corresponding error message. Consult https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500005343202-PostgreSQL-12-Upgrade-Error-database-user-hashicorp-is-not-the-install-user on how to work around this issue.

In my case:

```bash
psql postgres -U postgres
SELECT rolname, oid FROM pg_roles;
# check which role has oid 10, in my case role `postgres`
# – as we are postgres right now we have to create an temp user, continue with that:
CREATE ROLE "temp" WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION BYPASSRLS LOGIN PASSWORD 'temp';

exit # or Ctrl + D


psql postgres -U temp
ALTER ROLE $USER RENAME TO "$USER_";
ALTER ROLE postgres RENAME TO $USER;
CREATE ROLE "postgres" WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION BYPASSRLS;
```

Depending on your own databases you have to adapt these queries as described in the linked article.

P.S.: Be aware that upgrading old databases with an still installed postgis extension is not really worth the hassle, you have to either uninstall the extension or could another upgrade path as described in https://postgresapp.com/documentation/migrating-data.html.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this because the *target* database contained an extra user.

This was previously part of my install and upgrade init script. I removed it from the upgrade initdb and the upgrade completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

check `initdb.log` for both clusters, check from which older cluster (pg11) was initialized. We need to initialize new cluster with the same user, and there should be no other user created other than the initialized cluster user at target (pg14)